# Routes Guards causing wrong Route Navigation behavior

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-router-guards

I'm having an issue trying to navigate through different routes.

I have two different route modules.

**app.routes.ts**:

Containing only `LoginPage`:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginPageComponent,
    canActivate: [PreventLoggedInAccess]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'login'
  }
];

export const Routing: ModuleWithProviders = 
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash : true });
```

With **PreventLoggedInAccess.canActivate**, that, if the user is already logged in redirects him to the logged in section with `/app` prefix and child route `home`. It's defined as:

```
canActivate(): boolean {
  if (!this._authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
  }
  this._router.navigate(['/app/home']);
  return false;
}
```

**pages.routes.ts**:

Containing all `/app` subroutes that are accessible only if the user is logged in. This is achieved using `AuthGuardService.canActivateChild`:

```
export const pageRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: PagesComponent,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent },
      { path: 'contents', component: ContentsComponent },
    ]
  }
];

export const Routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(pageRoutes);
```

With the latter that redirects to `/login` if the user isn't logged in. It's defined as:

```
canActivateChild(): boolean {
  if (this._authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
  }
  this._router.navigate(['login']);
  return false;
}
```

> When I navigate from `app/home` to `app/contents` it only goes to `ContentsComponent` after navigating two times. So, if I do two times `this._router.navigate(['app/components']);` it works, if I do it only one time, the route changes from `app/home` to `app/route` for 1ms and it returns to `app/home`, while if I do it a second time it changes route.
>   While, if I'm in `app/contents` and try to navigate to `app/home` it changes route just fine.

`isAuthenticated` works fine. Both authguards work just fine, so, if I try to access any `app` child route when I'm not logged In I get redirected to login and If I try to access `login` when I'm logged In I get redirected to `app/home`.

I managed to debug a bit and I noticed the following flow:

- First attempt - `app/home` -> `app/contents`:

  - `navigate(['app/contents'])` is called
  - `PreventLoggedInAccess.canActivate` is called
  - `AuthGuardService.canActivateChild` is called
- Second attempt - `app/home` -> `app/contents`:

  - `navigate(['app/contents'])` is called
  - `AuthGuardService.canActivateChild` is called

Of course the expected behavior is the second one.

**EDIT**

Removing `this._router.navigate([/app/home]);` from `PreventLoggedInAccess.canActivate` solves the issue

```
canActivate(): boolean {
  if (!this._authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

But still, I do not understand **why `PreventLoggedInAccess.canActivate` is called when navigating to an `app` child even though `AuthGuardService.canActivateChild` is attached to it? Why is it called only on the first attempt?**

Comment: Try to use `enableTracing` to see what is happening: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash : true, enableTracing: true });`

Comment: Also worth checking what isAuthenticated() says there the first and second time.

Comment: What does your module look like? I wonder if the order of the merged routes are causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mentioned pageRoute can have all subchild of app 
so its routing file should contain that module.

So that concept of lazy loading and guards can be properly used.
I have answered this by assuming that your pageRoute module is child of App.

I suggest to use the AuthGuard only one time. AuthGaurd should be used on module containing other modules or components and not be on login component itself.

Here page module is lazy loaded and can be activated only if authguard returns
true
In case of false user will navigated to login.

**app.route.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },

];
```

**AuthGuard**

```
canActivateChild(): boolean {
  if (this._authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
  }
  this._router.navigate(['/login']);
  return false;
}
```

**Page.route.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: PageComponent,
     children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent },
  { path: 'contents', component: ContentsComponent },


     ]
  }
];
```

In case you want to debug in current routing condition you can use [Augury](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd?hl=en) from the Chrome web store.